# Why are my web-fonts not loading on my site?

Tags: css, fonts, font-face, webfonts

I've done as much searching around on Google and on here as I possibly could before posting so please excuse me if this is easy to answer. Perhaps it's just late where I am, I don't know.

The site is http://artofbackpacking.com

No matter what I do, the web fonts on the top right are not loading. You'll see that I have e001, e002, etc. They work in my development environment but not on my live site. The font is from icomoon.io and I used the CSS that was suggested on there. I also tried the Base64 code but that didn't work either.

Here's a small part of what I got in my CSS for this.

```
 @font-face {
font-family: 'socialFontsMichael';
src:url('../wp-content/fonts/socialFontsMichael.eot');
src:url('../wp-content/fonts/socialFontsMichael.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
    url('../wp-content/fonts/socialFontsMichael.woff') format('woff'),
    url('../wp-content/fonts/socialFontsMichael.ttf') format('truetype'),
    url('../wp-content/fonts/socialFontsMichael.svg#socialFontsMichael') format('svg');
font-weight: normal;
font-style: normal;
}
```

Appreciate the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to put `\` before `e000`, try this:

```
.social-feed:before {
    content: "\e000";
    background: #FF6600;
}
.social-feed:before hover {
    content: "\e000";
    background: #000;
}
.social-twitter:before {
    content: "\e001";
    background: #00aced;
}
.social-facebook:before {
    content: "\e002";
    background: #3b579d;
}
.social-instagram:before {
    content: "\e003";
    background: #dbd2c3;
}
.social-pinterest:before {
    content: "\e004";
}
.social-google-plus:before {
    content: "\e005";
    background: #c12026;
}
.social-youtube:before {
    content: "\e006";
    background: #ff3333;
}
```

How to use icon fonts: http://gomakethings.com/icon-fonts/

Comment: The world is a better place because of stackoverflow.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you have your paths incorrect I'm getting 404's on your font url's. Try just using "/wp-content/fonts/socialFontsMichael.woff' for example. That seems to be a valid url to me.

Answer (score 1):

You have a problem with files name (uppercase) or folders permission:

**Console errors:**

[image: Console Errors]

Try to change the permission of "fonts" folder, or maybe the cause is the fonts files names with uppercase "socialFontsMichael", change it to lowercase like "socialfontsmichael".

Comment: Thanks Arbaoui. I've fixed the path and permissions but they still appear not to be showing. I don't get those console errors.